# How to fetch data from another row in sql without joining the table with itself

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table :

```
Date        ID1    ID2  ID3    Data1    Data2

JAN-17        1     7    1       2       3
JAN-17        1     7    2       3       4
Feb-17        1     7    1       3       4
MAR-17        1     7    1       2       3
JAN-17        2     8    1       4       1
FEB-17        2     7    1       1       2
MAR-17        2     7    2       1       2
```

The composite key for the table is Date+ID1+ID2+ID3.

The output should  be :

```
Month  ID1    ID2   ID3                 Data
Jan-17  1     7       1        Data2(Jan)+Data2(Feb)+Data2(Mar(3+4+3)
Feb-17  1     7       1        Data1(Jan)+Data2(Feb)+Data2(Mar(2+4+3)
Mar-17  1     7       1         Data1(Jan)+Data1(Feb)+Data2(Mar)(2+3+3)
```

Quarter starts from Jan, if the month is first month of quarter , output for first month should be should be :Data1 for firstmonth+Data2 for next 2 months

If the month is 2nd month of quarter , output should be Data1 from last month and data2 for 2nd month+data2 for 3rd month

If the month is 3rd month of quarter , output for 3rd month should be Data1 from first month+Data1 from 2nd month +Data2 for 3rd month .

I am using oracle database .
Can someone help .

Comment: Whats your logic for the requirement? It doesn't make sense except hard coding everything.

Comment: What tells you which month is the "first", "second", "third" month of the quarter? In business the fiscal year of a company very often does not follow the calendar year - the company I work for, for example, starts its fiscal year somewhere around Feb 1, and fiscal months are only loosely associated with calendar months. For reference: [The 4-5-4 Calendar](https://nrf.com/resources/4-5-4-calendar)

Comment: I understand Bob .For me Jan is the start of first quarter,april start of 2nd quarter

Answer (score 0):

As is very often the case, analytic functions can help.  In this case, you need to take advantage of the windowing capabilities of analytic functions.  That is: the ability to specify exactly which range of rows you want to aggregate using the `ROWS BETWEEN` syntax in the windowing clause.

In your case, you want to `PARTITION BY` the quarter, `SUM(data1)` for the rows in the quarter that are *before* the current row, and `SUM(data2)` for the rows in the quarter that are the current month or greater.  Then, add those two sums together.

(I am assuming the "+" in your question means a sum and not a string concatenation like in your sample results).

Like this:

```
with d ( month, id1, id2, id3, data1, data2 ) AS (
SELECT to_date('JAN-17','MON-YY'),1,     7,    1,       2,       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('JAN-17','MON-YY'),1,     7,    2,       3,       4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('Feb-17','MON-YY'),1,     7,    1,       3,       4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('MAR-17','MON-YY'),1,     7,    1,       2,       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('JAN-17','MON-YY'),2,     8,    1,       4,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('FEB-17','MON-YY'),2,     7,    1,       1,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('MAR-17','MON-YY'),2,     7,    2,       1,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('APR-17','MON-YY'),2,     8,    1,       4,       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('MAY-17','MON-YY'),2,     7,    1,       1,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('JUN-17','MON-YY'),2,     7,    2,       1,       2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT month, id1, id2, id3, 
nvl(sum(data1) over ( 
     partition by to_char(month,'Q-YYYY'), id1, id2, id3 
     order by month 
     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0)
 +
nvl(sum(data2) over ( 
     partition by to_char(month,'Q-YYYY'), id1, id2, id3 
     order by month 
     rows between current row and unbounded following),0) result
FROM d
order by id1, id2, id3, month
```